# FileLoadException with .NET 4

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, fileloadexception, opennurbs

I'm trying to build an application using the OpenNURBS toolkit [(see here)](http://opennurbs.org) and I'm getting a FileLoadException with the following message while debugging:

> Mixed mode assembly is built against
>   version 'v2.0.50727' of the runtime
>   and cannot be loaded in the 4.0
>   runtime without additional
>   configuration information.

The OpenNURBS toolkit is the only non-System assembly in the project at this point, so I know the problem is with that file. Where and what are these supposed configuration options? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the following config to the `app.config` file:

```xml
<configuration>
    <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

For details:

[<startup> Element @ MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx34a2h.aspx)